# 403 error on downloadUrl (Kotlin) in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Getting this error:

> E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

This too:

> E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
> The user does not have permission to access this object.
> Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
> E/StorageException: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Permission denied." }}
> java.io.IOException: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Permission denied." }}

When this code is hit in my android app:

```
val urlTask = uploadTask?.continueWithTask { task ->
 if (!task.isSuccessful) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Upload to Cloud Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

task.exception?.let {

     throw it
}

} imagesRef?.downloadUrl.....ERROR IS GENERATED HERE...
```

Started when I turned on email/password authorization and turned off the anonymous sign in, however, I turned the anonymous sign-in back on and make sure auth is not null before starting the upload.

```
        val auth = Firebase.auth
        val user = auth.currentUser
```

ALSO, IT SAVES THE UPLOADED IMAGES TO STORAGE NO PROBLEM...but won't download the Url.

Here are the rules in place for my Firebase Storage:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{imageId} {

      allow write: if request.auth != null;
      
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have not been able to find an answer to why it will upload but not download the URL.

Comment: Your rules only allow authenticated users to add data to Cloud Storage. Are you sure your user is authenticated before uploading a file?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Comment: @AlexMamo, the files upload to Firebase Storage without issue. The error is generated when downloadUrl runs. Inbound works, outbound fails?

Comment: @AlexMamo, thank you for the links. I will work through these and reply.

Comment: So most likely, your user is not authenticated when you try to read the file, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo I just added a Log.d statement and this is what it came back with. You are correct! It is null - "D/fragsuccess: auth status is null" I don't understand what is happening though. The auth is not null when I send the actual image file a few ms before, but when the request is made for the download auth.currentuser is null? Why would that be and what would be causing it?

Comment: @stroopwafel Can you post your full code? There might be something in the omitted code that we're missing.

Comment: Actually, @AlexMamo suggestions fixed the issue. I am ready to close this out. Alex if you post your comments as a post I can mark as the solution. Thank you!

Comment: @stroopwafel Good to hear that you have fixed the issue. I just answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is present due to the fact that your user is not authenticated when you try to read the file from Cloud Storage. To be able to read a file, you should always make sure your use is authenticated in Firebase. That being said, please check the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object against nullity before performing Cloud Storage operations.